# Running an installer from a windows share using ansible

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, winrm

I want to log into a Windows server using a local user, then map a network drive using an Active Directory user and run an installer from it automated with Ansible.

I followed the suggestion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222905/mapping-a-network-drive-on-a-windows-guest-using-ansible) to create a PowerShell script and do the mount and the install. I used that script as follows:

Inventory:

```
[winserver]
windows

[winserver:vars]
ansible_user="local_user"
ansible_password="P@ssw0rd"
ansible_connection="winrm"
ansible_winrm_cert_validation=ignore
win_user="domain\aduser"
win_pass="P@55w0rd"
```

task yaml:

```
---
  - name: Mount and run a script
    script: 'files/maprun.ps1 -map_user {{ win_user }} -map_password {{ win_pass }} -script z:\ascript.ps1'
```

And the `maprun.ps1` script contains the following:

```
param(
  $map_user,
  $map_password,
  $script
)
$PWord="$map_password"|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$myCreds=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($map_user,$PWord)
New-PSDrive -Name "Z" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\domain\share" -Credential $myCreds
echo Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $script
```

And I get the error:

```
New-PSDrive: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have
been terminated
```

Most hits talk about a double-hop problem, but I am trying to specify different credentials in the remote script, so this isn't a double hop problem. The other answer suggests this ought to be possible. The script works in interactive mode, so it is something to do with being in batch mode. Any ideas how I can get this to work?

I am using Ansible 2.3.1.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux. Windows is Windows Server 2012 R2. Scripts were manually typed, sorry for any typos.

Comment: Any chance the username or password contains spaces or other special characters, and needs quoting somehow? Not familiar with Ansible syntax, but for example  `-map_user "{{ win_user }}" -map_password "{{ win_pass }}"`

Comment: I had actually quoted the whole line (Changed to reflect that). The password is OK though, because if I change it to an incorrect password I get a different error: `New-PSDrive : The specified network password is not correct`

Answer (score -2):

I can make a few suggestions.

1. As you've written it, the script "maprun.ps1" must be saved in the "files" directory of your Linux controller machine.  If it is, the "maprun.ps1" script will be copied by Ansible to the remote host, executed and deleted.  If "maprun.ps1" is going to call "ascript.ps1" you need to copy "ascript.ps1" over to the remote host before calling "maprun.ps1" and have it's location defined in the context of "maprun.ps1".
2. You don't need parameter names before the args in your playbook "script:" command.
3. Args internal to your Ansible playbook need double curly brackets and quotes around them.
4. As an alternative to connecting to the network drive with the New-PSDrive command you could try the "net use" command as shown below.

So instead of

```
 script: 'files/maprun.ps1 -map_user {{ win_user }} -map_password {{ win_pass }} -script z:\ascript.ps1'
```

Try

```
  script: files/maprun.ps1 "Z:" "{{ win_user }}" "{{ win_pass }}" "z:\ascript.ps1"
```

Where maprun.ps1 contains the following...

```
# connect to a shared resource and run script
param(
    [string]$map_server,    
    [string]$map_user,
    [string]$map_password,
    [string]$script    
)
# connect to the network drive
net use $map_server $map_password /USER:$map_user
Invoke-Item (start powershell ((Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName) + $script))
net use $uncServer /delete
```

Comment: 1. Yes, maprun is saved in files. ascript.ps1 is in the share that I am trying to map as drive z. This doesn't work which is the point of my post.

Comment: 2. The script is tested and works.
3. I tried echoing out the parameters, and they are being passed correctly in this case. I tried a variety of quoting options.
4. Net use gives error 
    The user context supplied is invalid